# Fill empty object with output of command

Tags: powershell, foreach

My code is:

```
    # Command to show existing mobile profiles
    $CallProfiles=netsh mbn show profiles

    # Create empty object
    $DelProfiles = "" | Select-Object Name

     # fill in object 
  ForEach ($Line2 in $CallProfiles) {
        if ([regex]::IsMatch($Line2,"    ")){
            $DelProfiles.Name = $Line2 -replace "    ",""
            }
            }
```

The output of $CallProfiles varies in lines. For example:
[image: output netsh mbn show profiles]

I would like to put every line (except !!##MBIMModemProvisionedContextInternetProfile##8932002100293639334) in my object $DelProfiles.

I tried to do this with the foreach loop but I only manage to get 1 line in my $DelProfiles object..
[image: output $DelProfiles]

What am I doing wrong? 
I am only a beginner in coding so my knowledge is basic..

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$DelProfiles` should be an array of objects, not a single object. Now the `Name` property is only overwritten in each iteration.

Declare the empty array:

```
$DelProfiles = @()
```

Add an object with the `Name`property to the array:

```
$DelProfiles += [PSCustomObject] @{Name = $($Line2 -replace "    ","")}
```

Comment: I'd select only lines with curly braces and use `$Line2.Trim()`